# dplyr + ggplot2: Plotting not working via piping

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to plot a subset of my dataframe. I am working with dplyr and ggplot2. My code only works with version 1, not version 2 via piping. What's the difference?

Version 1 (plotting is working):

```
data <- dataset %>% filter(type=="type1")
ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=variable)) + geom_line()
```

Version 2 with piping (plotting is not working):

```
data %>% filter(type=="type1") %>% ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=variable)) + geom_line()
```

Error:

```
Error in ggplot.data.frame(., data, aes(x = year,  : 
Mapping should be created with aes or aes_string
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe the problem is that in the second `ggplot` you have to use `.` instead of `data`.

Comment: This was quick. Thanks!

Comment: please don't post the answer as an edit to your question, post it as an answer (you may have to wait a little while) ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solution for version 2: a dot . instead of data:

```
data %>% 
    filter(type=="type1") %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x=year, y=variable)) + 
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Technically, you could also leave out the `.` as in `iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa") %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()` for example, but it might be easier to read with the explicit `.`

Answer (score 9):

I usually do this, which also dispenses with the need for the `.`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  ggplot +
  aes(
    x = disp,
    y = mpg
  ) + 
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

During typing with piping if you reenter the data name as you have as I shown with bold below, function confuses the sequence of arguments.

`data %>% filter(type=="type1") %>% ggplot(***data***, aes(x=year, y=variable)) + geom_line()`

Hope it works for you.