# Subset/filter in dplyr chain with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, subset

I'd like to make a slopegraph, along the lines (no pun intended) of [this](https://rpubs.com/walkerke/slopegraph). Ideally, I'd like to do it all in a dplyr-style chain, but I hit a snag when I try to subset the data to add specific `geom_text` labels. Here's a toy example:

```
# make tbl:

df <- tibble(
  area = rep(c("Health", "Education"), 6),
  sub_area = rep(c("Staff", "Projects", "Activities"), 4),
  year = c(rep(2016, 6), rep(2017, 6)),
  value = rep(c(15000, 12000, 18000), 4)
) %>% arrange(area)


# plot: 

df %>% filter(area == "Health") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, 
            group = sub_area, color = sub_area), size = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, 
            group = sub_area, color = sub_area), size = 2) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 18) + 
  geom_text(data = dplyr::filter(., year == 2016 & sub_area == "Activities"), 
  aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, 
  color = sub_area, label = area), size = 6, hjust = 1)
```

But this gives me `Error in filter_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  object '.' not found`. Using subset instead of `dplyr::filter` gives me a similar error. What I've found on SO/Google is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009649/dplyr-ggplot2-plotting-not-working-via-piping) question, which addresses a slightly different problem.

What is the correct way to subset the data in a chain like this?

**Edit**: My reprex is a simplified example, in the real work I have one long chain. Mike's comment below works for the first case, but not the second.

Comment: How about replacing the `.` with `df`?

Comment: You can hack it through by using braces to explicitly specify where you want the incoming data.frame to be piped: `df %>% filter(area == "Health") %>% { ggplot(.) + geom_line(aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, group = sub_area, color = sub_area), size = 2) + geom_point(aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, group = sub_area, color = sub_area), size = 2) + geom_text(data = dplyr::filter(., year == 2016 & sub_area == "Activities"), aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, color = sub_area, label = area), size = 6, hjust = 1) }` I'm not sure it gives you what you want, but it's a plot, at least.

Comment: @MikeH. Thanks, that works! However, it needs the name of the dataframe in front of the variables in `aes()` (my real example is one long pipe, the dataframe is not created first). But thanks, that works when the data is in the global environment.

Comment: @alistaire Wow, that is a very intriguing way of doing it. Would you mind explaining how the brackets work in this case?

Comment: See `?magrittr::\`%>%\``. Normally pipes pass the result of the left-hand side to the first parameter of the right-hand side, but if you wrap the RHS in braces, it will only send the result to wherever you put the `.`, which lets you use it repeatedly or across multiple calls within a sub-pipeline.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for the explanation. I'll accept that as an answer if you want to write it up. Thanks for the help, either way, this works like a charm and it's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you wrap the plotting code in `{...}`, you can use `.` to specify exactly where the previously calculated results are inserted:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  area = rep(c("Health", "Education"), 6),
  sub_area = rep(c("Staff", "Projects", "Activities"), 4),
  year = c(rep(2016, 6), rep(2017, 6)),
  value = rep(c(15000, 12000, 18000), 4)
) %>% arrange(area)

df %>% filter(area == "Health") %>% {
    ggplot(.) +    # add . to specify to insert results here
        geom_line(aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, 
                      group = sub_area, color = sub_area), size = 2) + 
        geom_point(aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, 
                       group = sub_area, color = sub_area), size = 2) +
        theme_minimal(base_size = 18) + 
        geom_text(data = dplyr::filter(., year == 2016 & sub_area == "Activities"),    # and here
                  aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, 
                      color = sub_area, label = area), size = 6, hjust = 1)
}
```

[image]

While that plot is probably not what you really want, at least it runs so you can edit it.

What's happening: Normally `%>%` passes the results of the left-hand side (LHS) to the first parameter of the right-hand side (RHS). However, if you wrap the RHS in braces, `%>%` will only pass the results in to wherever you explicitly put a `.`. This formulation is useful for nested sub-pipelines or otherwise complicated calls (like a ggplot chain) that can't otherwise be sorted out just by redirecting with a `.`. See `help('%>%', 'magrittr')` for more details and options.

Answer (score 3):

Writing:

```
geom_text(data = df[df$year == 2016 & df$sub_area == "Activities",],...
```

instead of

```
geom_text(data = dplyr::filter(., year == 2016 & sub_area == "Activities"),...
```

makes it work but you still have issues about the position of the text (you should be able to easily find help on SO for that issue).