# Using table() in dplyr chain

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr, magrittr

Can someone explain why `table()`doesn't work inside a chain of dplyr-magrittr piped operations? Here's a simple reprex:

```
tibble(
  type = c("Fast", "Slow", "Fast", "Fast", "Slow"),
  colour = c("Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red")
) %>% table(.$type, .$colour)
```

> Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
>       Have you called 'sort' on a list?

But this works of course:

```
df <- tibble(
  type = c("Fast", "Slow", "Fast", "Fast", "Slow"),
  colour = c("Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red")
) 

table(df$type, df$colour)


       Blue Red
  Fast    1   2
  Slow    1   1
```

Comment: You could also use `df %>% group_by(type, colour) %>% tally()`

Comment: You can also do `df %>% select(type,colour) %>% table` (the `select` is in case you have other columns).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This behavior is by design: https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/00a1fe3305a4914d7c9714fba78fd5f03f70f51e/README.md#re-using-the-placeholder-for-attributes

Since you don't have a `.` on it's own, the tibble is still being passed as the first parameter so it's really more like

```
... %>% table(., .$type, .$colour)
```

The official magrittr work-around is to use curly braces

```
... %>% {table(.$type, .$colour)}
```

Comment: Ah! Same as another problem I had with the pipe, so (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007998/subset-filter-in-dplyr-chain-with-ggplot2). Looks like I'm a slow learner. Thanks!

Comment: I thought using `do` would also do the trick... I guess it's because the output of `table` is not a data frame so something like `df %>% do(as.data.frame(table(.$type, .$colour)))` which looks horrible

Answer (score 15):

The `%>%` operator in `dplyr` is actually imported from `magrittr`. With `magrittr`, we can also use the `%$%` operator, which exposes the names from the previous expression:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

tibble(
  type = c("Fast", "Slow", "Fast", "Fast", "Slow"),
  colour = c("Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red")
) %$% table(type, colour)
```

**Output:**

```
      colour
type   Blue Red
  Fast    1   2
  Slow    1   1
```

Answer (score 6):

I've taken to using `with(table(...))` like this:

```
tibble(type = c("Fast", "Slow", "Fast", "Fast", "Slow"),
       colour = c("Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red")) %>% 
  with(table(type, colour))
```

And similar to the way we might read `%>%` as "and then" I would read that as "and then with that data make this table".

Answer (score 2):

The **tabyl** function from **Janitor** package work with pipe well, a great substitute for the native table function.

```r
library(janitor)
#> Warning: package 'janitor' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test
mtcars %>%   tabyl(cyl, gear)
#>  cyl  3 4 5
#>    4  1 8 2
#>    6  2 4 1
#>    8 12 0 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>